# Lower Windows Explorer timeout when looking for mapped network shares that are not available on the network

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares, shared-folders, windows-10-pro

I have a Windows 10 Pro laptop that has some LAN network shares mapped to drive letters.

When my laptop is not at home, Windows Explorer is very slow to open. I assume because it is trying to connect the mapped network drive which is not there.

How can I lower the timeout so it doesn't hang for 30 seconds?

Comment: Under the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider`, the `RestoreConnection` DWORD value `0` used to block Explorer from auto-connecting to network shares. Does it still work for you? ([link](https://sites.google.com/site/tweakradje/windows/windows-tweaking?pli=1))